# Free Accommodation Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A town has three hotels. You have 10 vouchers for one-night stay for the first hotel, 15 for the second one, and 30 for the third one. The rules do not allow you to use vouchers for two consecutive nights in one hotel. Can you use them all for 10 + 15 + 30 = 55 consecutive nights changing the hotels each night?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Are you having difficulty in *deciding*  whether it is/isn't possible, or in *proving* that it can/can't be done ?

Comment: Consider how to separate the $30$ nights for the third hotel.